# Interpolating GPS coordinates in R based on coordinates of another object

Tags: r, prediction, interpolation

I am looking at a ship and a vessel being towed behind it. I have coordinates (in decimal lat and long) for the ship at 1 second intervals. However, I only have intermittent coordinates for the towed vessel, as the gps system cut out regularly.

I want to be able to interpolate the position of the towed vessel based on the position of the ship at each 1 second interval.

I attempted to use the approx function, but that does not take into account the position of the ship, and just interpolates linearly - so it works okay, but not great, since the coordinates are visibly offset at almost every point.

Is there a better way to do this? I also tried using a linear model, but I'm not sure how to do this as there are two response and explanatory variables - lat and long.

Currently I have a dataframe called finaldata with columns:

```
decimaltime, shiplat,shiplong,towedlat,towedlong
```

for all times at which GPS coordinates are available for the towed vessel

I also have a dataframe called shipframe with columns:

```
decimaltime, shiplat, shiplong
```

for all one second intervals throughout the duration of the cruise. I want to be able to interpolate towedlat and towedlong for the same time intervals, if at all possible.

What I previously attempted to do was:

```
newobject<-approx(finaldata$towedlong,finaldata$towedlat,method="linear",n=10344)
```

(There are 10344 total seconds)

Does anyone know a way to obtain more accurate interpolation?

Thanks very much in advance.

edit: added by request

```
    head(finaldata)

       shiptime  shiplat  shiplong   tpdrlat  tpdrlong
    1 0.8077431 58.00103 -15.58733 -58.00153 -15.58787
    2 0.8077546 58.00102 -15.58732 -58.00153 -15.58786
    3 0.8077662 58.00102 -15.58731 -58.00152 -15.58786
    4 0.8077778 58.00101 -15.58730 -58.00152 -15.58785
    5 0.8077894 58.00100 -15.58729 -58.00152 -15.58785
    6 0.8078009 58.00100 -15.58728 -58.00152 -15.58784


    head(finaldata)

    structure(list(shiptime = c(0.807743056, 0.80775463, 0.807766204, 
    0.807777778, 0.807789352, 0.807800926), shiplat = c(58.00102992, 
    58.00102323, 58.00101654, 58.00100994, 58.00100325, 58.00099655
    ), shiplong = c(-15.58733002, -15.58731841, -15.58730832, -15.58729992, 
    -15.58728831, -15.58728008), tpdrlat = c(-58.00152608,
    -58.0015251761993, -58.0015242723986,  
    -58.0015233685979,-58.0015224647972, -58.0015215609965
    ), tpdrlong = c(-15.58786616, -15.5878615925196, -15.5878570250392, 
    -15.5878524575587, -15.5878478900783, -15.5878433225979)), .Names =    
    c("shiptime", 
    "shiplat", "shiplong", "tpdrlat", "tpdrlong"), row.names = c(NA, 
     6L), class = "data.frame")

    dput(head(shipframe))

    structure(list(time = c(0.808009259, 0.808020833, 0.808043981, 
    0.808090278, 0.808113426, 0.808159722), lat = c(58.00086661, 
    58.0008599, 58.0008466, 58.00080827, 58.00079828, 58.00075996
    ), long = c(-15.58708, -15.58707329, -15.58705497, -15.58701171, 
    -15.58699497, -15.58696998)), .Names = c("time", "lat", "long"
    ), row.names = c(24L, 25L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 37L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. Could you edit your question to include a representative sample of your data (including timestamps for which there are readings for the towed ship as well as timestamps for which there aren't)? It would be best if you could paste, say, the output of `dput(head(finaldata))` and of `dput(head(shipframe))`.

Comment: Thanks for your response - that's it added to the original question.

Sorry for the messiness of the dput part, I haven't gotten the hang of these forums yet.